# Upgrading from TexMakerX to TexStudio on OSX

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

How do install TexStudio so that it keeps all of my settings from TexMakerX or will it simply overwrite the old program?

Answer (score 3):

I did it a few hours ago …

Just download the texstudio.dmg and drag the application to to you app folder it don’t overwirte TeXMakerX. You can start it as a second editor but it uses the tmx preferences.
I guess (didn’t tried it yet) you can delete the old tmx app without loosing the preferences (if you only delete the app form the application folder *without* AppCleaner or something like that)

I found a little bug: TeXStudio doesn’t find it’s icon.
Fix: Right-click > Show Package contens. Open `Info-plist` and change `texmakerx.icns` to `texstudio.icns`. Save.